# CABasic strokeEnd Animation is not working with customView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

on calling startAnimation() the stroke Animation is not showing up, however, on using UIView.animate inside startAnimation function, it is working fine, only CABasicAnimation is not working. I am not sure what's wrong with this code. The frame is also coming fine, just the animation not showing up.

```
class ToastView: UIView {

lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
    return label
}()

lazy var subLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    return shapeLayer
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    customInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    customInit()
}

private func customInit() {
    backgroundColor = .black
    self.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let constraints = [
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 2),
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 3),
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 4)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)

    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 4
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func startAnimation(toastMessage: String) {

    self.label.text = toastMessage
    self.layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, at: 0)
    subLayer.frame = layer.frame
    subLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
    subLayer.masksToBounds = true
    
    let strokeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    strokeAnimation.beginTime = 0
    strokeAnimation.fromValue = 0
    strokeAnimation.toValue = 1
    strokeAnimation.duration = 1.5
    strokeAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    
    subLayer.add(strokeAnimation, forKey: "")
    //animate coming up with message
}
```

}

Comment: Several issues ... but first: where are you setting the label's text? And, are you setting the frame of the Toast View (either explicitly or via auto-layout constraints)? Or, are you using the label's size (after the text is set) to control the toast view's frame?

Comment: @DonMag I want to use the label size to manage the width and height of the view, and I am connecting the custom view from storyboard

Comment: @DonMag adding the label inside startAnimation function

Comment: ok - so, should the view "snap" to fit the size of the text, and *then* you want the stroke animation? Or are you trying to animate the **size of the view** at the same time?

Comment: and how are you positioning the toast view?

Comment: toastView is position using a view in storyboard with fix dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are adding your `ToastView` in Storyboard, with fixed dimensions.

So, let's assume it's size is `200 x 40`, centered horizontally, 12-points from the top (of the safe area), so it looks like this:

[image]

If we call your `startAnimation(...)` func, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

So, the first issue is that you are setting the sublayer frame like this:

```
subLayer.frame = layer.frame
```

which offsets the bezier path. It should be:

```
subLayer.frame = self.bounds
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

If we zoom in, we can see a faint "green":

[image]

but that's not what you want. You've set `layer.masksToBounds = true`, so it ends up clipping the sublayer.

If we set `layer.masksToBounds = false`, we get this:

[image]

and zoomed in:

[image]

Still, only *slightly* more green showing.

So, let's also change to `subLayer.masksToBounds = true` to `subLayer.masksToBounds = false`:

[image]

[image]

and we see the `strokeEnd` animation just fine.

You didn't clarify what you're really going for... if this looks right, you should be on your way.

Note: A view's layer border will be drawn *on top of* any sublayers / subviews. So if you want the Green outline to cover the White outline, you'll need to take a few more steps.